# Per destination MTU on windows

Tags: windows, networking, routing

On windows, I'd like to have a mtu of 4000 to 192.168.0.0/16 and a mtu of 1500 to my default route.

Is this possible on windows? On linux it's a per route option.

Answer (score 0):

The MTU is a property of the NIC; with VLAN support it applies to the VLAN in question only, but there's no way to use different MTUs in Windows based on routing unless you use dedicated (virtual) NICs.

Comment: Sad :-( As there is PMTU discovery, there might be a low-level way of controlling MTU per destination: that information is somewhere. I just don't know how to access it.